# adding divs within contact form 7 form tag

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to add `<div class="content-inner"></div>` under the form tag in contact form 7 so the inner contents of the form will be wrapped.

here is my code so far:

```
<div class="form-container">
<div class="contact-heading text-center">
   <h1>Contact</h1>
</div>
<div class="form-content">
   <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="140" title="Contact"]' ); ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

I can't figure out where to place the div so it is inside my form tag. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you are looking to add something into some sort of container. I would suggest JS .prepend (insert at the beginning) and .append (insert at the end).

Answer (score 1):

You cant add div inside the contact form plugin shortcode.
But,you can add div when create and edit the form

**I use div for submit button**

```
<label class='contact_form_name'> Your Name <span style='color:red;'>*</span>
[text* your-name] </label>

<label class='contact_form_email'> Your Email <span style='color:red;'>* 
</span>
[email* your-email] </label>

<label class='contact_form_subject'> Subject<span style='color:red;'>*</span>
[text your-subject] </label>

<label class='contact_form_message'> Your Message<span style='color:red;'>* 
</span>
[textarea your-message] </label>
<div class='contact_form_submit'>
[submit "Send"]
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Wordpress admin section you can edit the form itself. In there you can see the form elements. You can just write your own HTML in there as well.

Comment: I don't see where to do that. Would I be editing the plugin directly? People have said I shouldn't do that because when there are updates my code will be overwritten.

Comment: I mean using the backend to edit the form. https://cacoo.com/diagrams/FnqQMMdp5w2u7FIE-8D451.png

Comment: avasssso  you need to add div on editor or contact from where you generate field for the from. that location you can use html tag and inside html you can place the short code for the form field like <div class="test">[firstname]</div>